# Background-Image Opacity Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a Homepage right now, and got a few Problems.

I got a Background-Image set to Cover in the Body:

```
body{
    opacity: 1;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    background-image: url(Background.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Now I want that to change the opacity of the whole body-tag to 0 with javascript.

```
$("body").css("opacity", "0");
```

Everything disappears except the background-image, although it's in the body-tag?
Any Ideas?

**UPDATE!!**
I uploaded the "problem-site" to a webspace.
[Website](http://pixeld.bplaced.net/Workbench/)

Just click on "Query" than click in any box and press ENTER to call the js-function.

Thanks!!

Comment: Vendor prefixes on the `background-size` property? No. Also, show us your current javascript in which makes everything disappear except for the background image.

Comment: @BetaSystems - You only need 50 rep to leave comments on other people posts. That's easy to obtain if you are an active user but effectively reduces the noise of one timers who don't know/care what the site's about and misuse comments.

Comment: I may be wrong, but opacity applies to that element and all its children. See http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made [a fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AwIDEDE/1/edit) with your code that reproduces the issue. Code can be simplified into this:

```
body{
    opacity: 0.1;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The root issue is that fiddling with the opacity of the `<body>` element doesn't have any effect unless you have something below. A simple fix is to add this:

```
html{
    background-color: white;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AwIDEDE/2/edit)

Comment: +1 Strange that having that the background on html makes it work!

Comment: Did work. Thanks! (Sorry, not enough reputation to Vote-Up ._.)

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason (I can't seem to find any references to why), setting `opacity:0` or `visibility:hidden` on the `<body>` tag has no effect on the `background-image`. It definitely has an effect an element with a background-image that is a child of the body tag. So you have two options:

**Add a wrapper `<div>` around the `<body>` content**:

Where you currently have:

```
<body>
    <!-- Content -->
</body>
```

Change this to:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

And move the `CSS` on body to `#wrapper` as well any Javascript/jQuery targeting body

**Set the opacity on the `HTML` element**

Wherever you are setting `opacity:0`, do it on the `<html>` element instead.

***Personally, I'd recommend the first option.***